# Java Script - how to return all results back to a function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have a part of code that works fine - it executes a query against a database and print out all rows (line 9 bellow) . However I want to return back results to outside of function so that can parse results further etc.

```
function execute_query() {
    connection.execute({
      sqlText: 'show databases',
      complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
        } else {
          for (row in rows) 
            // Line 9: console.log(JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2));
        }
      },
    });
}

console.log(execute_query());
```

How to achieve that goal within a snippet above?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using an `async` function and a `Promise`.

```
function execute_query() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
    connection.execute({
      sqlText: 'show databases',
      complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
        if (err) {
          reject('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
        } else {
          resolve(rows);
        }
      },
    });
  });

}

async function main() {
  try {
    let result = await execute_query();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your way of executing this script? Did not return anything for me..

Comment: @Joe the way is described within the answer.

Comment: Do you mind adding a bit more light to it?